# Making a pythonic decision on developing a web scraper module

Tags: python, import, module, coding-style

This is a fairly high level question.
I have developed many different web scrapers that work in different websites.

I have many different versions of the functions named getName() and getAddress().

Is it pythonic/not terrible coding practice to do this in the function of a module? If this is bad to do, could someone give me a high level tip on how to manage this kind of library-of-scrapers?

```
def universalNameAdressGrab(url):
   page = pullPage(url)
   if 'Tucson.com' in url:
       import tucsonScraper
       name = getName(page)     #this is the getName for Tucson
       address = getAddress(page)
   elif 'NewYork.com' in url:
       import newyorkScraper
       name = getName(page)   #this is the getName for NewYork
       address = getAddress(page)
   return {'name':name, 'address':address}
```

Comment: You're going to run into all sorts of fun with the import cache in that design, I'd think. Don't go for it.

Comment: Details: http://www.dabeaz.com/modulepackage/

Comment: Thanks, I am going to watch that tutorial now.

Comment: what is  `('name':name, 'address':address)`? Is that supposed to be a dict?

Comment: Thanks Padraic, I have fixed it (maybe). If it is still wrong feel free to edit it (or if you can't then just post the correct line here).

Comment: BTW, you're not supposed to give the `.py` extension when you `import`. And after `import tucsonScraper` you'd call that module's `getName` function by `tucsonScraper.getName(page)`.

Comment: Thank you 2Ring, I have changed the .py extension in the code above. Also, am I right in saying that if I use the tucsonScraper.getName(page), then I can just import all the scrapers and then use the functions that I need by using that method?

Comment: @Rorschach: Yes! The usual thing is to import all required modules at the top of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably more pythonic to import everything at the top of the file. After that you can reference the functions by module and remove a lot of duplicated code. You may run into issues with URL capitalization, so I would standardize that as well. You could use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) for that. I would consider something like the following more pythonic:

```
import tucsonScraper
import newyorkScraper

def universalNameAdressGrab(url):
    page = pullPage(url)
    scraper = None

    if 'Tucson.com' in url:
        scraper = tucsonScraper
    elif 'NewYork.com' in url:
        scraper = newyorkScraper
    else:
        raise Exception("No scraper found for url")

    return {'name': scraper.getName(page), 'address': scraper.getAddress(page)}
```

Comment: Thank you @natdempk. This definitely looks better and I will plan on using this way of doing it for now. I will wait until the end of the day before accepting this answer just in case someone comes by with a better one.